why components are not rendering,but path is changing?
I tried to wrap my button in Link tag with to="/path" propertie,and tried to replace Button tag with Link tag but components still doesn't renders.
here all react component i use, i cant find what's wrong
App.jsx
import {
  Route,
  createBrowserRouter,
  createRoutesFromElements,
  RouterProvider,
} from "react-router-dom";
import Auth from "./componentsa/Auth";
import SuccesLogIn from "./pages/SuccesLogIn";
import Register from "./pages/Register";
const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route path="/" element={<Auth />}>
      <Route path="/succesLogIn" element={<SuccesLogIn />}></Route>
      <Route path="/register" element={<Register />}></Route>
    </Route>
  )
);
function App() {
  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
}

export default App;


Auth.jsx
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const Auth = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  return (

        <div className="flex flex-row gap-3">
          <Link
            to="/succesLogIn"
            onClick={() => navigate("/succesLogIn")}
            className="w-24 font-bold p-3 rounded-xl text-white text-xl
            hover:-translate-y-1 bg-slate-500 active:bg-slate-600 transition"
          >
            LogIn
          </Link>
          <Link
            to="/register"
            onClick={() => navigate("/register")}
            className="w-24 font-bold  p-3 rounded-xl text-white text-xl hover:-translate-y-1 bg-slate-500 active:bg-slate-600 transition"
          >
            Register
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Auth;


SuccesLogIn.jsx
const SuccesLogIn = () => {
  return <div>You are loged in</div>;
};

export default SuccesLogIn;


Register.jsx mostly likely as a Auth file

Also just FYI, the Link component already handles navigating to the target path, there's no need at all for any onClick handler to imperatively navigate there too.
